# Adding a global monitor with NSEvent.EventTypeMask mask does not trigger

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsevent

I'm developing a Mac application for the menu bar to manage a list of values copied via command + c. I would like my app to perform actions when I press that key combination, even when it is not active. I tried using the addGlobalMonitorForEvents method but it never gets triggered.

```
//
//  iMemoStackApp.swift
//  iMemoStack
//
//  Created by Cristiano Aloigi on 30/11/23.
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct iMemoStackApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("iMemoStack", systemImage: "list.bullet.clipboard") {
            ContentView()
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
    
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var keyMonitor: Any?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("start")
        let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(
                    [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String: true] as CFDictionary)
        print(accessEnabled)
        startMonitoringKeys()
    }
    
    func startMonitoringKeys() {
        keyMonitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { (event: NSEvent) in
            if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command)
                && event.characters == "c" {
                print("comando copia eseguito")
            }
            if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command)
                && event.characters == "v" {
                print("comando incolla eseguito")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopMonitoringKeys() {
        if let keyMonitor = keyMonitor {
            NSEvent.removeMonitor(keyMonitor)
            self.keyMonitor = nil
        }
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ notification: Notification) {
        stopMonitoringKeys()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your app have accessibility permission?

Comment: Yes, I add a piece of code that checks that: let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(
                    [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String: true] as CFDictionary)
        print(accessEnabled)

Comment: Your code works. Remember that for accessibility permission to work you also need to remove *app sandboxing* in "Signing & Capabilities"